# specific loop for array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I already have the main method(not shown here) in eclipse. The code would print

```
days 1: 5
days 1: 2
days 1: 6
days 2: 5
days 2: 2
days 2: 6
days 3: 5
days 3: 2
days 3: 6
```

What should the code be if i want to have the output as

```
days 1: 5
days 2: 2
days 3: 6
```

*Code:*

```
int days[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; // each loop
int months[] = { 5, 2, 6 };

for (int i : days) {
    for (int g = 0; g < 3; ++g) {
        System.out.println("days: " + i + ", " + months[g]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of two nested loops, create just one loop, which goes from `0` to the length of the `days` array. In the body of the loop, print the corresponding elements from `days` and `months`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
    // print days[i] together with months[i]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int days[] = {1, 2, 3};     //each loop
int months[] = {5, 2, 6};   
for(int g = 0; g < days.length; g++)
{
  System.out.println("days: " + days[g] + ", " + months[g]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this code

```
for(i=0;i<days.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println("days: " + days[i] + ", " + months[i]);
}
```